# Distance between lattice planes of a lattice with two different atoms

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

I know that the distance between two adjancent lattice plane of the same family is given by
$$
d=\frac{a}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2+l^2}}
$$
if we use the conventional cell of a cube with volume $a^3$. I also know that we need to exclude the systematic extinctions by calculating the structure factor.

In the case of two different atoms in a lattice, with their atomic form factors $f_1$ and $f_2$, the structure factor is:
$$
S_G=\sum_if_i \cdot exp(-i\vec{G} \cdot \vec{r_i}).
$$

Now suppose that I have gotten to a result:
$$
S_G = f_1 x + f_2y$$
and the values of $x$ and $y$ are:
$$
x = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & h , k ,l \, \  \text{all even}\\
0 &  \text{all other cases}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$$
y = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & h , k ,l \, \  \text{same parity}\\
0 &  \text{all other cases}
\end{array}
\right..
$$

I want to calculate the distance between the planes in $111$ direction. Now my question is: Is $(111)$ a valid point of the reciprocal lattice (Can I use $111$ to calculate the distance between the lattice planes in $111$ direction?)? I see that $x = 0$ and $y = 1$, so the structure factor is not zero and this should be a valid point. However, I am not sure if I am leaving some type $1$ atoms out in between two $111$ planes with a seperation $d= a/ \sqrt3$ (calculated using $111$),since I have $x=0$.

Comment: So this is a Bravais lattice with a two-atom basis?

Comment: Yes. The example given is a fcc lattice with two type $1$ atoms on $(0,0,0)$ and $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$ and a type $2$ atom on $(1/4,1/4,1/4)$, if I did my math correct. But I want to ask the general case, e.g if in the structure factor some atomic form factors vanish what is the correct way of choosing the points of the reciporcal lattice.